# Is daylight time symmetrical between northern and southern hemisphere?

Tags: earth-rotation

At lat +50.0 on Jun 21 and lat -50.0 on Dec 21 is the time between sunrise and sunset exactly the same?  And so on throughout the parallels and the days of the year?

If not can you explain why?  I once read something about the earth's wobble on its axis means that daylight length is not symmetrical north to south.

Comment: Solstices occur in June & December, there are large differences between daylight hours during solstices. It's more likely that equal daylight hours would occur during the equinoxes in March & September

Comment: Required viewing: [VSauce 'How Earth Moves'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJhgZBn-LHg)

Comment: Fred I'm talking about comparing daylight hours between north and south.  I'm not asking if the the solstice daylight is longer than equinox daylight.

Comment: USNO publishes sunrise/sunset tables, and you could look at these, but they might not be accurate enough for your purposes. You can try HORIZONS as well. I suspect they will slightly different because the Earth's orbit is elliptical, and the perihelion and aphelion nearly coincide with the solstices.